# PDO SELECT from SLAVE and INSERT into MASTER

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

is there any chance to set in PDO settings that SELECT's will be executed on SLAVE DB server and Insert & Update & DELETE will be executed on MASTER DB server, or I need to create PHP handler to do that?

Situation:

We have **Master** - **Master** replication for MySQL. We are going to add two new servers so it will be - **Master**/**Slave** - **Master**/**Slave**.

I want to create some handling for **SELECT** queries. I want execute **SELECT** queries on **SLAVE** instead of **MASTER** and all **UPADTE&INSERT&DELETE** queries will be executed on **MASTER**. Is this possible with some setting?

Thanks!

Comment: If you use Doctrine DBAL you can easily do this http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.5/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Connections.MasterSlaveConnection.html , however if you have your own DB interaction with some wrapper class then you have to write your own code for handling the same.

Comment: It is possible to do this with the MySQL Native Driver: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.rwsplit.php

Comment: Thanks for asking this question  and its very useful  @Abhik + chris

Comment: As already stated this is not possible. And it could be extremly dangerous, if this could be possible. The reason is simple. If you make all selects go to a slave, and that slave is a few moments behind the master (could be just a fraction of seconds), you might get not up-to-date information. For critical information this could be a desaster. So you need to write some logic of your own, because only you can decide what selects could go to new slave and what should always go to the master.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't configure PDO or any of PHP's database extensions to do this. That is simply because each PDO (or MySQLi, etc.) instance represents a single connection, to a single server.

So yes, you'll need a handler that is aware of multiple connections to do that. Some popular ORMs and other database-abstraction layers do provide such functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not doing it even if you could.  Replication is "asynchronous".  That is, when you insert into the Master, there is no assurance that it will arrive at the Slave before you try to read it.  Nor even any guarantee that it will arrive today!

If you user posts a comment on a blog, and then goes to a page that shows the comment, they will be annoyed if the comment does not show.  They may assume that the comment was lost and then repost it.  This causes *you* grief when users complain about double-posting.

This is called "critical read".  This simple way to avoid the mess is to be careful about what you send to the Slaves -- namely nothing that would lead to "disappearing" posts.

There are various "proxy" packages that allow from the read-write split you describe; some try to avoid the "critical read", but I don't trust them.

A Galera Cluster (see PXC, MariaDB), does *synchronous* reads, so it can avoid the critical read problem.  (There is, however, a setting you need to apply.)

Comment: Rick James - its the best solution to do that. You also can use MaxScale (also with MAriaDB Galera Cluster) to select the correct Server. This includes also the failover. I vote up

Comment: 3y3skill3r - you can also install MaxScale on the server where you use PDO and MaxScale will select the correct Server